# How to make a jquery UI drag and drop element responsive which has position property absolute?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-ui, responsive

I am trying to build a website builder application using Jquery UI. I am able to do that for desktop view but now i want to convert the same template into tablet and mobile responsive view.

Below is the frontend code for desktop view.

```
<div class="document-page ui-droppable" id="container-ground" style="position:relative;width:960px;height:1200px;">
 <div id="contactForm" class="right-column element ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle ui-resizable" onclick="showToolBar(this.id,&quot;Contact Form&quot;,event)" style="width: 425.017px; padding: 10px; position: absolute; left: 521.448px; top: 273.597px; z-index: 100001; height: 746.976px;">
    <div class="form-top">
       <h2 class="contact_title">
          <p>LEAD FORM</p>
       </h2>
       <h5 class="contact_desc">
          <p>Please add your details</p>
       </h5>
    </div>

 </div>
 <div id="footer" class="element textcontent footer_div ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle ui-resizable" onclick="showToolBar(this.id,&quot;Footer&quot;,event)" style="display: block; position: absolute; left: 0.989624px; top: 1181px; z-index: 100003; width: 960px; height: 98.507px;">
    <div id="copyright" class="subelement copyright footer_div1" ondblclick="edit(&quot;&quot;,this.id)" style="width:100%; text-align: center;" onclick="showMiniToolbar(this.id,event)">
       <p>Double Click To Edit</p>
    </div>
    <div id="links" onclick="showMiniToolbar(this.id,event)" class="subelement links footer_div1" style="text-align: center;">
       <ul style="display:block;" class="footer-menu">
          <li style="display:inline-block;margin-right:10px;"><a style="" href="http://192.168.1.32/landing/Homecontroller/frontend/homePage/59e0b3f0756d0fc6373c9869">Home</a></li>
          <li style="display:inline-block;margin-right:10px;"><a style="" href="http://192.168.1.32/landing/Homecontroller/frontend/cookie/59e0b3f0756d0fc6373c9869">Cookie Policy</a></li>
       </ul>
    </div>
 </div>
 <div class="element ui-draggable-dragging ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle ui-resizable" id="header_div" style="height: 145px; display: block; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 47.7674px; z-index: 100002; width: 960px;" onclick="showToolBar(this.id,&quot;Header&quot;,event)">
    <div class="subelement header_column_logo ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle ui-resizable" id="header_column_logo" style="display: inline-block; position: absolute; left: 30.9791px; width: 200px; height: 75px; top: 33.9931px;" onclick="showHeaderToolbar(this.id)"><span class="logo-span" id="logo_span" data-content="Click to Upload Image" style="display:inline-block;" ondblclick="uploadImage(this.id);"><img id="header_image" class="header_image subelement" src="http://192.168.1.32/landing/uploads/uploaded_image_231017022917" style="height: 75px; width: 200px;"></span></div>
    <div class="free_text subelement ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle ui-resizable" id="header_text" onclick="showImageToolbar(this.id,event)" style="width: 249px; text-align: center; display: inline-block; position: absolute; left: 290.958px; top: 44.9861px;" ondblclick="showEditor(this.id)">
       <p>&nbsp;</p>
    </div>
    <div class="free_text subelement ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle ui-resizable" id="header_column_contact" onclick="showImageToolbar(this.id,event)" style="display: inline-block; width: 225px; position: absolute; left: 652.976px; top: 58.9757px;" ondblclick="showEditor(this.id)">
       <p>&nbsp;</p>
    </div>
 </div>
 <div class="free_text element ui-draggable-dragging ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle ui-resizable" onclick="showImageToolbar(this.id,event)" style="padding: 10px; text-align: center; position: absolute; left: 85.2119px; top: 302.719px; z-index: 100004; height: 67.7778px;" ondblclick="showEditor(this.id)" id="free_text171441">
    <span class="free_text171441">
       <p>TEXT1</p>
    </span>
 </div>
 <div class="free_text element ui-draggable-dragging ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle ui-resizable" onclick="showImageToolbar(this.id,event)" style="padding: 10px; text-align: center; position: absolute; left: 109.212px; top: 512px; z-index: 100005; height: 67.7778px;" ondblclick="showEditor(this.id)" id="free_text171442">
    <span class="free_text171442">
       <p>TEXT2</p>
    </span>
 </div>
 <div class="free_text element ui-draggable-dragging ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle ui-resizable" onclick="showImageToolbar(this.id,event)" style="padding: 10px; text-align: center; position: absolute; left: 362.212px; top: 333.719px; z-index: 100006; height: 67.7778px;" ondblclick="showEditor(this.id)" id="free_text171443">
    <span class="free_text171443">
       <p>TEXT3</p>
    </span>
 </div>
 <div class="element ui-draggable-dragging ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle ui-resizable" onclick="showImageToolbar(this.id,event)" style="width: 300px; height: 220px; overflow: hidden; position: absolute; left: 165.212px; top: 703.177px; z-index: 100007;" ondblclick="uploadImage(this.id);" id="free_image171444"><img src="http://192.168.1.32/landing/assets/images/no-image.jpg"></div>
 <div class="element ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle ui-resizable" onclick="showImageToolbar(this.id,event)" style="width: 300px; height: 220px; overflow: hidden; position: absolute; left: 594.931px; top: 546.375px; z-index: 100008;" ondblclick="uploadImage(this.id);" id="free_image171445"><img src="http://192.168.1.32/landing/assets/images/no-image.jpg"></div>
 <div class="element ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle ui-resizable" onclick="showImageToolbar(this.id,event)" style="width: 300px; height: 220px; overflow: hidden; position: absolute; left: 195.198px; top: 412.813px; z-index: 100009;" ondblclick="uploadImage(this.id);" id="free_image171446"><img src="http://192.168.1.32/landing/assets/images/no-image.jpg"></div>
```

All the styles are inline with position absolute.
So how can i convert this code into tablet and mobile responsive view?

Below is the extraction of inline CSS for all the elements.

```
    #footer {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0.989624px;
    top: 1097.55px;
    z-index: 100003;
    width: 960px;
    height: 98.507px;
}
#header_div {
    height: 145px;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 47.7674px;
    z-index: 100002;
    width: 960px;
}
#free_text171441 {
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    left: 85.2119px;
    top: 302.719px;
    z-index: 100004;
    height: 67.7778px;
}
#free_text171442 {
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    left: 109.212px;
    top: 512px;
    z-index: 100005;
    height: 67.7778px;
}
#free_text171443 {
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    left: 362.212px;
    top: 333.719px;
    z-index: 100006;
    height: 67.7778px;
}
#free_image171444 {
    width: 300px;
    height: 220px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    left: 165.212px;
    top: 703.177px;
    z-index: 100007;
}
#free_image171445 {
    width: 300px;
    height: 220px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0.989624px;
    top: 641.361px;
    z-index: 100008;
}
#free_image171446 {
    width: 300px;
    height: 220px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    left: 195.198px;
    top: 412.813px;
    z-index: 100009;
}
```

Now how can i convert width ,height ,top and left to mobile and tablet respectively ?Is there any formula or logic to convert ?

I will give you a example what exactly i want...

There is a image which having a property of

```
For desktop
#free_image171446 {
    width: 891px;
    height: 325px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    left: 34.5px;
    top: 133px;
    z-index: 100009;
}

For tablet
#free_image171446 {
    width: 764px;
    height: 278.6px;
    left: 0px;
    top: 133px;   
}

For Mobile
#free_image171446 {
    width: 320px;
    height: 116.72px;
    left: 0px;
    top: 283px;   
}
```

I need to convert like this dynamically.

https://jsfiddle.net/4wkqm9rm/

Comment: If you use !important in a css selector, it will trump your inline styling. So you should be able to use a media query (https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/) to override the existing classes for the elements involved, and set their position to relative...

Comment: how can i convert width ,height ,top and left to mobile and tablet respectively ?Is there any formula or logic to convert ? @Toby

Comment: it's hard to say without knowing more about what layout you are trying to achieve. If you really want things positioned proportionately depending on the size of the screen, then you could use percentages in your CSS instead of absolute values. Then everything's width, height, top and left will vary depending on the size. Is that what you want? @Puneeth

Comment: @Toby - I will give you a example what exactly i want...

There is a image which having a property of

For desktop
#free_image171446 {
    width: 891px;
    height: 325px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    left: 34.5px;
    top: 133px;
    z-index: 100009;
}

For tablet
#free_image171446 {
    width: 764px;
    height: 278.6px;
    left: 0px;
    top: 133px;   
}

For Mobile
#free_image171446 {
    width: 320px;
    height: 116.72px;
    left: 0px;
    top: 283px;   
}

I need to convert like this dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

Working with absolute properties for size or positioning is not a good start for a responsive design. If you're not into rewriting it, you should have in mind that you'll find many problems down the road, because of that.

What you can do now is use some [media queries](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries_ex.asp) for mobile/tablet/laptop screen sizes, in your CSS, in order to override those absolute values you have, with the ones you need for each device.

You might also need to use a library like [touchpunch](http://touchpunch.furf.com/), because sometimes jquery ui doesn't handle touch events very well.

Comment: Will the element width and position will change automatically ? @ Antonis

Comment: @PuneethKumar Yes. Once the conditions of your media query are true,  the browser will use the properties described in the media query.

Try [this](https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=tryresponsive_mediaquery) example from W3 Schools to see how it works.

Comment: I will give you a example what exactly i want...

There is a image which having a property of

------For desktop------
#free_image171446 {
    width: 891px;
    height: 325px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 34.5px;
    top: 133px;
    z-index: 100009;
}

-------For tablet------
#free_image171446 {
    width: 764px;
    height: 278.6px;
    left: 0px;
    top: 133px;   
}

-------For Mobile-------
#free_image171446 {
    width: 320px;
    height: 116.72px;
    left: 0px;
    top: 283px;   
}

I need to convert like this dynamically.